# how can GoogleMap composable be personalized?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I'm doing a project on Compose with Google Maps SDK for Android. I'm trying to customize all the UI on the map, I know that this can be done with the old library of GoogleMaps but I don't know how to do it on new compose library.

I want to change markers, remove default places markers, change font style, customize actual location button, etc... I've taken a look into [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose?hl=es-419) but it is very poor, the unique solution that I have found is to use the old library, but if it's the only one solution it's a pity because the new library makes all much easier.

Here is the implementation of GoogleMap into my composable:

```
@Composable
fun DiscoverContent(
  mapState: MapState,
  setupClusterManager: (Context, GoogleMap) -> ZoneClusterManager,
  calculateZoneViewCenter: () -> LatLngBounds,
  onClusterClicked: (ZoneClusterItem) -> Unit
) {

  val context = LocalContext.current
  val mapProperties = MapProperties(isMyLocationEnabled = mapState.lastKnownLocation != null)
  val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState()

  GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    properties = mapProperties,
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    uiSettings = MapUiSettings()
  ) {

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    MapEffect(mapState.clusterItems) { map ->
      if (mapState.clusterItems.isNotEmpty()) {
        val clusterManager = setupClusterManager(context, map)
        map.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager)
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager)
        clusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener { cluster ->
          val clusterItem = cluster.items.firstOrNull()
          clusterItem?.let { onClusterClicked(it) }
          true
        }
        map.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
          if (mapState.clusterItems.isNotEmpty()) {
            scope.launch {
              cameraPositionState.animate(
                update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                  calculateZoneViewCenter(),
                  MAP_PADDING
                )
              )
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here I upload a screenshot of how it looks right now. [How map looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEizq.png)

Comment: Can you please provide more information as to what you mean as "Personalize"? And what hinders you in doing modifications? What do you mean by old library? Can you provide the link?

Comment: @Yrll Yes of course! I mean personalize to change the markers image, color, also hide the locations of near restaurants, supermarkets, change the color of the water, the ground, and more... These things on the old library was able to do it with mapStyle that was defined on styles.xml, i mean the old library to the library not made for compose, the implementation of this library was different and a bit more difficult https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling?hl=en-419

Comment: Please do note that Jetpack Compose is Android’s modern toolkit for building native UI. It simplifies and accelerates UI development on Android. Which also takes away the customizability to a certain extent. Also, what you mean by "Old Library" is the Maps SDK for Android itself without the toolkit right? If so, calling it "Old" I think is not relevant. Because what the Jetpack Compose uses is still that same Maps SDK for Android. It just helps things be simpler and easier to implement. If your priority is customizability, you better stick with the standard Maps SDK without the toolkit.

Comment: @Yrll Yes sorry for the missunderstanding, it's not old library. I'll do what you say, use the Maps SDK without the toolkit for compose. Anyway, i think it has to be implemented to customize on the compose toolkit without having to create an xml file to customize it.

Comment: Yeap you are right. You can see it [here in the github repo](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose#creating-and-configuring-a-map) that you can still modify the map. But also it was mentioned a little below it that certain use cases may require extending the GoogleMap object to decorate / augment the map. It can be obtained with the MapEffect Composable. But doing so can be dangerous, as the GoogleMap object is managed by the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to customize some aspects of GoogleMap composable. In mapProperties parameter of GoogleMap composable you can add mapStyleOptions like this

```
val mapProperties = MapProperties(
    isMyLocationEnabled = mapState.lastKnownLocation != null,
    mapStyleOptions = MapStyleOptions(styleJson)
  )
```

then you pass a .json with all thinks that you want to customize, in my case I only wanted to delete the poi markers (default markers that come in default map, like restaurants and supermarkets) and also change color of water and delete road labels. I figured it out passing this .json

```
val styleJson = """
    [
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#CDE2F0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
""".trimIndent()
```

I hope it helps to all the people who is trying to implement a GoogleMap on his project!